# Condition that runs once a timer invalidates

Tags: swift

I currently have a timer app with the code below. I was wondering how i can program a condition (for example a label displaying a message) once the timer reaches 00:00. Would it just be a simple if statement? And if so, how would that look?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
var countdownTimer: Timer!
var totalTime = 60
func startTimer() {
countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: 
#selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func updateTime() {
timerLabel.text = "\(timeFormatted(totalTime))"

if totalTime != 0 {
        totalTime -= 1
    } else {
        endTimer()
    }
}
func endTimer() {
    countdownTimer.invalidate()
}
func timeFormatted(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
    let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes: Int = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Comment: It looks like you should just put your statement in your `endTimer` method.

Comment: You already have that condition as the else part of this `if totalTime != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we can tell, in your code, `endTimer` could be called from the outside to stop the timer. So that's not the best location.

- I would rename `endTimer` to `timeIsUp` or similar and make this callback private (to guarantee you're not calling it from anywhere else.
- Have a `public func stopTimer()` instead to invalidate the timer.
- Call `stopTimer` from `timeIsUp`

So `timeIsUp` would be the place to put your message.

Apart from this refactoring suggestion, in your current code, I'd put the message stuff inside the `else { endTimer() }` block of code since that's where your "time is up" condition is met.

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
var countdownTimer: Timer!
var totalTime = 60
func startTimer() {
    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTime() {
    timerLabel.text = "\(timeFormatted(totalTime))"

    if totalTime != 0 {
        totalTime -= 1
    } else {
        // ⬅️ put the message code here
        endTimer()
    }
}
func endTimer() {
    countdownTimer.invalidate()
}
func timeFormatted(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
    let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes: Int = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
}
```